# Getting DOM from page using Chromium/WebKit

Tags: webkit, chromium

Trying to get access to a page's DOM after rendering.  I do not need to view the page and plan to apply this programmatically without any GUI or interaction.

The reason I am interested in post-rendering is that I want to know where objects appear.  Some location information is coded in the HTML (e.g., via offsetLeft), but much is not.  Also, Javascript can change the ultimate positioning.  I want positions that are as close to what the user will see as possible.

I've looked into Chromium code and think there is a way to do this but there is not enough documentation to get started.

Putting it *VERY* simply I'd be interested in pseudo-code like this:

```
DOMRoot *r = new Page("http://stackoverflow.com")->getDom();
```

Any tips on starting points?

Comment: What do you mean by "DOM after rendering" as the DOM will be the same but the rendered page will be vastly more complicated. Chrome/Chromium already has the programatic ability to yield the computed page with the Developer Tools → Elements and Chromium is open source so you may want to look there.

Comment: updated in response to your question, thanks!  i'll check out the dev tools, but i am sure some small sample code must be possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the Web API wrapper that Chromium exposes; specifically, the [WebDocument](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/public/web/WebDocument.h) class contains the functionality that you need.  You can call it like this:

```
WebFrame * mainFrame = webView->mainFrame();
WebDocument document = mainFrame->document();
WebElement docElement = document->docElement();

// Manipulate the DOM here using docElement
...
```

[You can browse the source code for Chromium's Web API wrapper here.](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/public/web/)  Although there's not much in the way of documentation, the header files are fairly well-commented and you can browse Chrome's source code to see the API in action.

It's difficult to get started using Chromium.  I recommend looking at the [test_shell application](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/webkit/tools/test_shell/).  Also, a framework like the [Chromium Embedded Framework](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) (CEF) simplifies the process of embedding Chromium in your application; I use CEF in my current project and I'm very satisfied with it.

Comment: Chromium source code link is moved [here](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebKit/chromium/public).